# Team Development of HTML5 PhoneGap App

Tags: debugging, mobile, cordova, remote-debugging

First, I don't know if this is the right place to make this question but, I don't see any other place where to put it.

I would like to know how could I develop a mobile HTML5 App (using PhoneGap) with another friend, without need to have a copy of the project in more than one PC.

Could I somehow host the Code on a FTP Server and then we both could work on it for example, on Eclipse?

Comment: You can use some Source Control System like Git or Mercurial?

Comment: But isn't git used only for version control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without need to have a copy of the project in more than one PC.

How should that be possible? When want to view view something on your local computer, you must have it available on your local computer. But I think I know what you are looking for, three suggestions:

1. Use a cloud-based IDE. [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) for example is one of the best. However, all of them tend to be slow and buggy.
2. Just synch the files between your computers. One of the best hosted services is [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), or you can install [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) on your own Server.
3. Use a version control system. This is pretty common for software development as you can easily reproduce who made which change when and why. The best option is [git](http://git-scm.com/) and [Github](https://github.com/) for hosting.

Comment: Ok, I think I will use git then. Thanks =)

Comment: While I agree in general, cloud file hosts are not a stable solution for software development. Source control is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into using a source control system of some kind. Source control comes in many flavors, but in general it allows software developers to sync code between many servers, and allows developers to work concurrently without breaking each other's environments (imagine I have to take a component offline for many hours to code on it, but other people rely on it to do their work).

The two most common source control solutions are SVN and Git. Both of these work on Mac/Linux/PC and are documented thoroughly online.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is months late, but check out Adobe's Phonegap Build. Build and deploy in the cloud. They also allow you to assign a development team.
www.adobe.com/PhoneGap